# not able to save document with id 0 into mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, nosql

I am using spring data mongodb for jdbc transactions. i am facing really strange problem . when i am calling save method of collection repository. it throwing duplicate key exception in case id value is 0 . but if id value is >0 it works fine .

i have checked documents into collection , document with id 0 and 32158 both are there but

repository.save(domain entity with id value 0) --> Failed due to duplicate key exception

while

repositroy.save(domain entity with id value 32158) -->succeed with updated time stamp.

is there any restriction from mongodb site for document with id 0

Comment: Long Data type is being used .

Comment: I had a similar problem once but I was using `long` not `Long`.

Comment: I tried with long and also with Long, in both cases it is working